# SAS array dimension error

Tags: arrays, sas

```
data t1;
    M = 4;
    array a1{M} _temporary_ (2, 3*1);
    array a2{M} _temporary_(4*.);
run;


ERROR: Too many variables defined for the dimension(s) specified for the array tables.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: an integer constant, *.  

ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Why I can't define the dimension of an array by other variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define the dimension like that, rather you can use `Macro` to achieve the same like below

```
 %let   M = 4;
  data t1;
    array a1{&M.} _temporary_ (2, 3*1);
    array a2{&M.} _temporary_(4*.);
run;
```

Comment: Just to add reason (this was too long for an edit): You cannot use a data step variable to define the size of an array because arrays are created when the DATA step compiles, before any of the assignment statements have executed.